# SharePoint High Trust some users getting 401

Tags: csom, sharepoint-on-prem, 401, high-trust-app

Hi I've created a High Trust application, but some users seem to be getting the 401 from time to time.
I've got a hunch that it's down to them not logging off and something not 100% accurate with their AD account. Basically maybe something with the claims in their profile and that's causing an issue. Would this ring true to anyone.

We do tell users to log off each night and power down their machines - but not too sure if they are.

Anyone had any experience in this field?

Comment: 401 means the user has not been successfully authenticated.  SharePoint cannot make any decisions based on claims or who the user is because the user is unknown at this point in the process.

Comment: Thanks, it's just odd that this seems to just happen to a few people and we are on an intranet so I know who the person is. They can access the SharePoint site direct. But still a couple of 401s. I'm just trying to figure out why?!

Comment: Could be any number of things.  Is the app domain setup and in the local intranet zone (assuming Internet explorer)?

Comment: Yeah should be... just tricky to pin down....  could always be a user machine problem...... I guess just trying a keep with it - try and get users to try again / give them a nice error page etc.

Comment: Thing is (sorry for not being clear) the issue seems to 'self resolve' given a few seconds or so.